# Logstash Grok filter add local hostname

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I have a 4 instance Nagios Log Server cluster that processes logs from multiple servers. I would like a log entry to have the name of the Log server that processed it. I have been looking at the 'add_field' and trying to get something to work that takes the name of the local processing log server and adds it as a field called "processingLogServer";

```
    if [type] == 'Log' {
    grok {
        match => [ 'message', '%{TIME:logTime}%{GREEDYDATA:logEntry}' ]
    }
    mutate {
        remove_field => [ '@version', 'highlight', 'port', 'SourceModuleType', 'EventReceivedTime', 'message' ]
add_field => [ 'processingLogServer', 'hostname' ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I needed was to use ruby, as per https://discuss.elastic.co/t/logstash-hostname-as-field/146662

```
filter {
  ruby {
    init => "require 'socket'"
    code => "event['some-field-name'] = Socket.gethostname"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [environment variables](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/environment-variables.html) in your logstash configuration file. So you can use that to add server-dependent information to your logs:

On Windows, the `COMPUTERNAME` environment can be used for that:

```
mutate {
    add_field => { "processingLogServer" => "${COMPUTERNAME}" }
}
```

On Linux system, you should be able to use the `HOSTNAME` environment variable.

---

Or you can use the `host` field, that's automatically created and set by logstash.

You can copy the content of a field like this:

```
mutate {
    add_field => { "processingLogServer" => "%{host}" }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I am using redhat. I've tried updating my filter with your suggestion but it seems to take the "${hostname}" as a string so the raw output shows;

"processingLogServer": "${hostname}"

Comment: @t2022 I can't test on redhat, but you should be able to check the available environment variable with `printenv`. And keep in mind that environment variable are case sensitive on Linux, so `${HOSTNAME}` should be used.

Comment: I've tried both upper and lowercase, but both are returned as a text field. On the CLI if i type HOSTNAME it says "command can not be found". If I type hostname it gives me the name of the log server. Interestingly "printenv" lists it as HOSTNAME.

Comment: @t2022 I have a better solution. You can used instead the `host` field that's automatically created by logstash and copy it in `processingLogServer`. I'll update my answer

Comment: I've tried that and it does at least read it as a variable, however it returns the IP of the host the log is coming from, rather than the name of the receiving log server.

Comment: @t2022 my bad, I was testing with logs coming from stdin, so I missed that.